# InvalidJobConfException. Output directory not set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to write some data into bigtable using a `SparkSession`

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .config(conf)
  .appName("my-job")
  .getOrCreate()

val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration

import spark.implicits._
case class BestSellerRecord(skuNbr: String, slsQty: String, slsDollar: String, dmaNbr: String, productId: String)

val seq: DataFrame = Seq(("foo", "1", "foo1"), ("bar", "2", "bar1")).toDF("key", "value1", "value2")

val bigtablePuts = seq.toDF.rdd.map((row: Row) => {
  val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)))
  put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("nbr"), Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)))
  (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put)
})

bigtablePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(hadoopConf)
```

But this gives me the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:138)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.assertConf(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:391)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
```

which is coming from

```
bigtablePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(hadoopConf)
```

this line. Also I tried to set the different configurations using `hadoopConf.set` such as `conf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")` but this gives me a `NullPointerException`.

How may I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to upgrade to the mapreduce api, as the mapred is deprecated.

This question here shows an example of rewriting this code segment: [Output directory not set exception when save RDD to hbase with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340202/output-directory-not-set-exception-when-save-rdd-to-hbase-with-spark?rq=1)

Hope this is helpful.